# How to use Corona textures in Blender?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have a model with textures made for the Corona renderer. The textures are: Diffuse, Glossiness, Height, IOR, Normal, Reflection. How can I use them in Blender Cycles? The following setup seems to work, but I don't really know what I'm doing, especially with respect to the Reflection and IOR texture:

[image]

Additional remarks:

1. I can't upload the model because it's a commercial product.
2. The IOR to Specular converter is from [Blendernation](https://www.blendernation.com/2018/11/05/blender-3d-tip-realistic-specular-value-in-principled-shader/).
3. I read somewhere that Corona uses DirectX normal maps, not sure if
       that's true.
4. I guess the height map isn't really necessary, given that there's
   already a normal map?